# How to get the right xpath for this node? scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm new at using web scrapy and I've been trying to get the right xpath from this portion of the code.

[from this website](https://tecomgroup.ae/directory/company.php?company=0016F00001wcgFJQAY&csrt=2648526569298119449)

[hmtl code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7LZx.png)

I've been using this scrapy commands:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="companycontent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div').getall()
```

This is the Output:

```
['<div class="address">\r\n                                    <h4>Address <span>1</span></h4>\r\n                                    <strong>Office : </strong>1715 , 1714<br>\r\n                                    <strong>Floor : </strong>Floor 17<br>\r\n                                    <strong>Building : </strong>Shatha Tower<br>\r\n                                    Dubai Internet City<br><br>\r\n                        \t\t</div>']
```

> > > response.xpath('//*[@id="companycontent"]/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7LZx.png)/div/div[6]/div').get()
> > > '\r\n                                    Address 1\r\n                                    **Office :** 1715 , 1714
> > > \r\n                                    **Floor :** Floor 17
> > > \r\n                                    **Building :** Shatha Tower
> > > \r\n                                    Dubai Internet City
> > > \r\n                        \t\t'

And this one:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "address")]/text()').extract()
```

with the output:

```
['\r\n                        \r\n                            \r\n                        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                                ', '\r\n                                    ', '\r\n                                    ', '1715 , 1714', '\r\n                                    ', 'Floor 17', '\r\n                                    ', 'Shatha Tower', '\r\n                                    Dubai Internet City', '\r\n                        \t\t', '        \r\n                        \t\t\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t                            \r\n                    ']
```

> > > response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "address")]/text()').getall()
> > > ['\r\n                        \r\n                            \r\n                        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t                                ', '\r\n                                    ', '\r\n                                    ', '1715 , 1714', '\r\n                                    ', 'Floor 17', '\r\n                                    ', 'Shatha Tower', '\r\n                                    Dubai Internet City', '\r\n                        \t\t', '        \r\n                        \t\t\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t                            \r\n                    ']

I'm sure the first command will do the job but I was wondering if there's a shorter xpath command to run the script.
Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding text by xpath follow as `//tag-name[@class="class-name"]`  you can follow this approach and find the data

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://tecomgroup.ae/directory/company.php?company=0016F00001wcgFJQAY&csrt=2648526569298119449")
data=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="address"]')
data.text.split("\n")
```

Output:

```
['ADDRESS 1',
 'Office : 1715 , 1714',
 'Floor : Floor 17',
 'Building : Shatha Tower',
 'Dubai Internet City']
```

Comment: that output is what I'm looking for. So I have to use Selenium for this. Is it possible to use both scrapy and selenium together in the same python code?

Comment: Oh sorry i thought you are working with `selenium` you can use selenium but I dont know about `scrapy` so you can try both combination from SO!

Answer (score 0):

You could use also css selector `response.css('div.address > div.address ::text')`

```
print(`[x.strip() for x in response.css('div.address > div.address ::text').getall() if x.strip()]`)
```

Comment: I've never used css selector... I might have to give it a good read on this.